# How can I log errors and user actions in Windows Azure (MVC)?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Azure is changing so quickly so could someone give me some suggestions on how could I could log:

- Errors
- Exceptions
- User Actions

I would like to be able to log these to table storage so they can be retrieved with code and viewed on administrative web pages.  I am not looking so much for code but what I really want is to know where I should look. Azure changes so fast I want to be sure to use what's best.

Thank you

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I just did something similar on the weekend. I ended up just creating 1 table called "LogEvents" and used the provider key to separate the different types of log events and dates (e.g. the ProviderKey = "20111121_LoginEvent" when someone logged in on 21 Nov).

For me the queries can then be done quite easily on date/type and display the result on an admin page

Not sure if this is the best way but it seems to be working for me. I did search Google but couldn't find anything that really did this.

---

Update 1:
The class I use is called LogEvent:

```
public class LogEntry : TableServiceEntity
{
    public LogEntry(string logType)
    {
        if (LogType == null || LogType.Length == 0)
        {
            if (logType.Length > 0)
                LogType = logType;
            else
                LogType = "Default";
        }

        PartitionKey = string.Format("{0}_{1}", LogType, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("yyyyMMdd"));
        RowKey = string.Format("{0:10}_{1}", DateTime.MaxValue.Ticks - DateTime.Now.Ticks, Guid.NewGuid());
    }

    public LogEntry()
    {

    }

    public string Message { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogDateTime { get; set; }
    public string LogType { get; set; }

}
```

I just create a new instance of it and set the properties:

```
LogEntry le = new LogEntry("Default") { Message = "Default Page Loaded", LogDateTime=DateTime.Now };
        LogEntryDataSource ds = new LogEntryDataSource();
        ds.AddLogEntry(le);
```

To get the data back out again I just use a standard Linq query and pass in the date and LogType:

```
    public IEnumerable<LogEntry> GetLogEntries(string eventType, DateTime logDate)
    {
        var results = from g in this.context.LogEntry
                      where g.PartitionKey == String.Format("{0}_{1}", eventType, logDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd"))
                      select g;
        return results;
    }
```

There's probably a better way but this was pretty simple to setup and it's working for me

Comment: Can you show what the table LogEvents looks like? I am also interested. How do query on date/type?

Comment: I think it is better if you use the built-in diagnostics functionality in Azure rather than making custom diagnostics, see my reply for more info on how to do this.

Comment: Thanks Inge. As I said in my post I was sure there is a better way, but I couldn't find the built-in diagnositcs which is why I built that myself. I will be changing over to it.

Answer (score 5):

Azure has built in functionality logging and tracing, see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx

for more information on the subject.

Here is how I have used Azure diagnostics myself:

Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics;

namespace CrossCuttingConcerns
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This class handles diagnostics and stores the logs in the Azure table and blog storage.
    /// Note: Basically all logs are turned on here, this can be expensive and you may want to change several settings here before going live
    /// </summary>
    public class AzureDiagnostics
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Sets how often diagnostics data is transferred to the Azure table storage or blob storage
        /// Note: Change to a period that fits your need, commenting out one of these lines disables it
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="diagnosticMonitorConfiguration"></param>
        void SetDiagnositcManagerScheduledTransferPeriods(DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration)
        {
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Directories.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.DiagnosticInfrastructureLogs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.PerformanceCounters.ScheduledTransferPeriod = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will add a full crashdump. 
        /// Note: Full crashdumps are not available in asp.net roles
        /// </summary>
        void AddFullCrashDumps()
        {
            CrashDumps.EnableCollection(true);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Enables performance counters
        /// Note: PerformanceCounterConfiguration.CounterSpecifier is language specific and depends on your OS language.
        /// Note: For a complete list of possible PerformanceCounterConfiguration.CounterSpecifier values run "typeperf.exe /Q"
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="diagnosticMonitorConfiguration"></param>
        void AddPerformanceCounterMonitoring(DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration)
        {
            var performanceCounterConfiguration =
                new PerformanceCounterConfiguration
                {
                    CounterSpecifier = @"\Processor(*)\% Processor Time",
                    SampleRate = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
                };

            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.PerformanceCounters.DataSources.Add(performanceCounterConfiguration);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// By default all Windows events to the Application and System logs are stored in the Azure table storage
        /// Note: Decide here what Windows event logs you are interested in seeing, you can also filter out events
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="diagnosticMonitorConfiguration"></param>
        void AddEventLoggingFromWindowsEventLog(DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration)
        {
            // Syntax: <channel>!XPath Query
            // See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd996910(VS.85).aspx
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("Application!*");
            diagnosticMonitorConfiguration.WindowsEventLog.DataSources.Add("System!*");
        }

        void StartDiagnosticManager(DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration diagnosticMonitorConfiguration)
        {
            DiagnosticMonitor.Start("DiagnosticsConnectionString", diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
        }

        public void EnableAzureDiagnostics()
        {
            var diagnosticMonitorConfiguration = DiagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();

            SetDiagnositcManagerScheduledTransferPeriods(diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);

            AddFullCrashDumps();
            AddPerformanceCounterMonitoring(diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
            AddEventLoggingFromWindowsEventLog(diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);

            StartDiagnosticManager(diagnosticMonitorConfiguration);
        }
    }
}
```

Config:

```
  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace>
      <listeners>
        <add type="Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener, Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" name="AzureDiagnostics">
        </add>
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>
```

Answer (score 4):

There have been further changes to Azure logging....

Logging via Trace.TraceXXXX (e.g. Trace.TraceInformation) will now be logged to the Windows Azure file system (~\LogFiles\Application*.txt).

You'll need to get ftp access to the Web Site (enable via Azure Management Portal/Dashboard/Deployment Credentials) to see these files.

Logging must first be enabled from the Settings page of the Web site which you can access either from Visual Studio (Server Explorer/Windows Azure Web Sites/Site Name/View Settings) or from the Azure Management Portal (under Configure/Application Diagnostics/Application Logging).

These logs can also been seen from the live Windows web Azure site from the Visual Studio Output Window (make sure you select "Windows Azure Logs - xxx" in the "Show Output From" dropdown) if you right click on the web site in the Visual Studio Server Explorer (under Windows Azure Web Sites) and select "View Streaming Logs in Output Window".

Logging to the Visual Studio Output window is covered in Scott Gu blog (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2013/04/30/announcing-the-release-of-windows-azure-sdk-2-0-for-net.aspx)

NB: I've only tried this in VS2012.  Not sure if it also works in VS2010.