# Publishing a webapp to azure along with database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, web-applications

I'm trying to publish a version of '`GeekQuiz`' to `azure` as a `webapp`. It looks like I've managed to get everything exported except the database since information isn't being loaded in at all.

The `TriviaContext` is where the `database` appears to be created:

```
public class TriviaDatabaseInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TriviaContext>
```

However there were no `databases` defined in `manage.windowsazure.com`, so I created one (`sql database`) and got the `connection string` for it and ran that via the `packagemanager` console (`Update-Database -Verbose -ConnectionString ...`) then I ran `Enable-Migrations -ContextTypeName GeekQuiz.Models.TriviaContext`.

Everything seems to have run without issues but the webapp still doesn't work and I'm pretty sure it's because the database is not being created.

Is there any steps I can take to diagnose this problem or am I doing something wrong? I'm very new to this and I couldn't find any tutorials or info on publishing a database so I could be completely off base here.

When I run the seed method this is the `SQL` I'm seeing, notice there is no data being input for trivia:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TriviaAnswers] (
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [OptionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [UserId] [nvarchar](max),
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TriviaAnswers] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TriviaOptions] (
    [QuestionId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [IsCorrect] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TriviaOptions] PRIMARY KEY ([QuestionId], [Id])
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TriviaQuestions] (
    [Id] [int] NOT NULL IDENTITY,
    [ImageClip] [nvarchar](max),
    [ImageDir] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.TriviaQuestions] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
)
CREATE INDEX [IX_QuestionId_OptionId] ON [dbo].[TriviaAnswers]([QuestionId], [OptionId])
CREATE INDEX [IX_QuestionId] ON [dbo].[TriviaOptions]([QuestionId])
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TriviaAnswers] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TriviaAnswers_dbo.TriviaOptions_QuestionId_OptionId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionId], [OptionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TriviaOptions] ([QuestionId], [Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TriviaOptions] ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.TriviaOptions_dbo.TriviaQuestions_QuestionId] FOREIGN KEY ([QuestionId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[TriviaQuestions] ([Id]) ON DELETE CASCADE
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] (
    [MigrationId] [nvarchar](150) NOT NULL,
    [ContextKey] [nvarchar](300) NOT NULL,
    [Model] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
    [ProductVersion] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.__MigrationHistory] PRIMARY KEY ([MigrationId], [ContextKey])
)
INSERT [dbo].[__MigrationHistory]([MigrationId], [ContextKey], [Model], [ProductVersion])
VALUES (N'201509240441274_AutomaticMigration', N'GeekQuiz.Models.TriviaContext',  0x1F8B0800000000000400ED5ADD6EDB3614BE1FB0771074B50DA915A7375B60B7489DA408D6246DEC16BB0B68E9D8214A511A496576873DD92EF6487B851DFD4BD48F253B4ED262C84D4CF3FCF0F07C3CE477FCEFDFFF8C5EAF5C66DC8390D4[snip (lots of stuff here)] , N'6.1.1-30610')
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesnt work'? What errors are you getting?

Comment: The questions and answers don't load, the website doesn't have any errors exposed to a user but the monitor show there are errors - I'm not sure how I can view them.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/i25etKH.png

Comment: Well, the first problem is that the errors are getting swallowed up and (presumably) not being logged. You should fix that first. Secondly, you may have created the database, but are you sure you seeded/inserted questions and answers into the database?

Comment: Where is a good place to look to set up error logging? I would have assumed there would be a site log somewhere on the azure portal that would have it...

I'm not sure if the database is seeded correctly, after I ran the enable-migrations command it did a bunch of stuff and finished off with 'Running Seed method', there were no errors reported.

Comment: Now that I think of it - Azure might be catching the global exceptions for you. You might need to FTP in and take a look in the `Logs` folder. Other than that, I'd look into `log4net` and setup either (or both) filesystem and database logs. If you have `SQL Server Management` installed on your machine, you should also be able to connect to the DB and investigate whether or not the entries have been created. A third option is to update your local web.config to point to azure's DB and test it locally

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16975865/563532